# Completion handler only gets called if it wasn't called before

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift4, completionhandler

My application receives location updates, and when it does (if they are relevant), I call an API asynchronously using a completion handler. When the application opens, the completion handler responds only if there was no request that finished before (two requests come in at the same time usually). When I debug, after the first 2-3 requests (which come in at the same time) where everything works, when the location update passes as relevant, the whole completion handling part of code gets skipped.

This is how I call the completion handler:

```
        if conditions {
            let lat = Float(loc.lat)
            let long =  Float(loc.long)
            // calls function using completion handler in order to add new location
            BusStations.allBusStations(lat: lat, long: long) { (busStations, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    // got an error in getting the data
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                guard let busStations = busStations else {
                    print("error getting all: result is nil")
                    return
                }
                if !busStations.stops.isEmpty || self.locations.isEmpty {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I make the API call:

```
    static func allBusStations (lat: Float, long: Float, completionHandler: @escaping (BusStations?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let endpoint = BusStations.endpointForBusStations(lat: lat, long: long)
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not construct URL")
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            guard error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let stations = try decoder.decode(BusStations.self, from: responseData)
                completionHandler(stations, nil)
            } catch {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                print(error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is data returned when the location update passes as relevant?

Comment: not from the completion handler. The debugger gets inside the if, assigns lat and long, and then just skips the whole "allBusStations" call.

Comment: If nobody will reply soon, I'd suggest to make a small minimal project, where this issues reproduces and upload it to Github. With this in hands, it would be much easier to figure out the cause. For me it more looks like a memory management issue.

Comment: I tried to debug it again and it entered inside the completion handler now. I have no idea why. I did not change anything to code that would affect that. What should I do? delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to dispatch the completion handler to global or main queue to see if it is deferred by system to execute on a queue of lower levels.